# How to define and train a Recurrent Neural Network with different set of parameters for each layer, and loss function based on intermediate values?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function

By studying neural networks I understand that usually, RNNs share the same parameter for each time.

How can I define (in Keras) an RNN that has different set of parameters for each time and also a loss function that depends on every intermediate hidden output/input value?

I still haven't tried because I cannot find relevant sources for this question.

Comment: This is not an RNN, its just a simple dense layer.